# Docusign integration

Tags: integration, administration, docusign

I am trying to setup Docu Sign for my company and I did all the steps and I got stuck on this.
When I press the custom button provided by DocuSign Send with DocuSign that is added to all page layouts. I keep getting this error.

> The SourceID value for this DocuSign Custom Button is invalid. Please
>   ask your Salesforce administrator to correct the custom button
>   configuration. See the DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator Guide for
>   more information.

I really don't know what to do. I am totally stuck.

Here is the code behind the custom button, generated by DocuSign.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
```

The error MSG:
[image]
Please advise,

Darko

Comment: can you share the code or URL behind the custom button.

Comment: Sure I've edited the question. Please check it out.

Comment: Our issue were permissions. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Necro-answer!

Regardless, I couldn't find an answer to this particular issue, but I found one. I tried the different documentations and couldn't get passed the error you were getting.I felt it would be better to answer this one instead of creating a new thread.

I came across the following link:
https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-admin-guide/Content/admin-guide/sample-js-code-custom-buttons.htm

It has a larger button example, and for whatever reason, this one was able to work properly once adjusted to work with my specific custom sObject, Project__c.

I've included my own code examples, which does have the code block from the above URL in it as well.

Attempt 1 - did not work after a lot of tweaking

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript?SourceID{!Project__c.Id}")}DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
```

Attempt 2 - did not work after a lot of tweaking

```
var SourceID2 = window.sfdcPage.getEntityId();
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID="+SourceID2;
```

Debugging block to attempt to see if there was anything extra I needed from the source ID. There wasn't.

```
var SourceID1 = window.sfdcPage.entityId;
var SourceID2 = window.sfdcPage.getEntityId();
var SourceID3 = '{!Project__c.Id}';
var SourceID4 = DSGetPageIDFromHref(); 

console.log('This is the value of window.sfdcPage.entityId: '+SourceID1);
console.log('This is the value of window.sfdcPage.getEntityId(): '+SourceID2);
console.log('This is the value of !Project__c.Id: '+SourceID3);
console.log('This is the value of DSGetPageIDFromHref(): '+SourceID4);
```

**This last block worked after changing the sObject at the very end to be the one I wanted. Besides that I didn't have to edit it at all. If you're looking to copy/paste a solution from this thread, it's this entire below piece you want.**

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//

```
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';
var RROS='';var CCRM='';varCCTM='';
var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';
var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';
var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';
var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
```

//*************************************************//

// Modify individual options here:
// Related Content (default no related content)

```
RC = ''; /*Ex: GetRelContentIDs("{!Opportunity.Id}");*/
// Recipient Signer Limit (default no limit)
RSL = ''; //Ex: '3'
// Recipient Starting Routing Order (default 1)
RSRO = ''; // Ex: '1'
// Recipient Routing Order Sequential (default not sequential)
RROS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Custom Contact Role Map (default config role)
CCRM = ''; /*Ex: 'Decision Maker~Signer1;Economic Buyer~Carbon Copy'*/
// Custom Contact Type Map (default Signer)
CCTM = ''; /*Ex: 'Decision Maker~Signer;Economic Buyer~CC'*/
// Custom Contact Note Map (default no note)
CCNM = ''; /*Ex: 'Decision Maker~Note for DM;Economic Buyer~Note For EB;DEFAULT_NOTE~Default Note'*/
// Custom Related Contact List (default object contact)
CRCL = '';     /*Ex:'MyContacts__r,Email~Email__c;FirstName~First_Name__c;LastName~Last_Name__c;Role~Role__c,LoadDefaultContacts~0'*/
// Custom Recipient List
CRL = ''; /*Ex:'Email~;FirstName~;LastName~;Role~SignInPersonName~;RoutingOrder~;AccessCode~;RecipientNote~;SignNow~, LoadDefaultContacts~1'*/
// One Click Option (default edit envelope screen)
OCO = ''; //Ex: Tag
// DocuSign Template ID (default no template)
DST = ''; //Ex: '67870A79-A0B5-4596-8AC1-CC7CC1EA01EB'
// Load Attachments (default on)
LA = ''; //Ex: '0'
// Custom Email Message (default in config)
CEM = ''; //Ex: 'Envelope sent by [FirstName] [LastName] ([Email])!'
// Custom Email Subject (default in config)
CES = ''; //Ex: 'Re: Opportunity Name: {!Opportunity.Name}'
// Show Tag Button (default in config)
STB = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Send Button (default in config)
SSB = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Email Subject (default in config)
SES = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Email Message (default in config)
SEM = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Reminder/Expire (default in config)
SRS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Chatter (default in config)
SCS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Reminder and Expiration Settings
RES = ''; //Ex: '0,1,2,0,120,3'

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
```

//This section is the one you change. Change the sObject reference to the one you want.

```
//Edit the reference to the sObject in the line below
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!sObject.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+
RSL+"&RSRO="+
RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+
CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+
LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+
SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please refer this. It may help you.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures

In the 9 the step of the above link you find this. If I am not wrong you were missing the merge field in the Id part.

**/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript?id={!your Object .Id}**

I am expecting your url should look like this

Comment: Hi Suri,
Thanks for the reply but unfortunately this doesn't work :(.
The code above that is presented in the button perfectly works for opportunities but when you try to add it to Accounts,Leads etc... it blocks giving this MSG that i just edited above.